# What is the API used by Disqus?

Tags: disqus

Disqus back-end is written in Django.

Do they use Django rest framework for their API to serve million of communities ?

If other, which one is currently used for making billions of requests to the server each month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disqus uses flask api, as mentioned in the book thirdparty javascript by Ben Vinegar-one of Disqus programmer